# Is there an exhaustive list of options that fingerprintjs takes?

Tags: javascript, fingerprint, fingerprintjs2

Where can I find an exhaustive list of `options` that I can give to the `Fingerprint2.get(options, callback);` function of [Fingerprintjs](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)?

I see the [`defaultOptions` object in the source code](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/blob/master/fingerprint2.js#L236) but that only lists the default values for select parameters.

Comment: This isn't it…?! https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2#options

Comment: @deceze Far from it. That's a very limited set.